# Only get the numbers out of an URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I only want to have the numbers of my URL as return. At the moment I use:

```
alert(document.URL);
```

to get the whole URL. But is there any other easy solution to get only the ID-Numbers from my URL as result? I also use jQuery and PHP in this project.

Comment: Give us an example of a URL

Comment: maybe ur looking for query string
[query string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var numbers = document.URL.match(/\d+/g)` will return all numbers in a URL (eg for this thread) `document.URL.match(/\d+/g)` => `["19570840"]`

Comment: Thats exactly what i searched for! Thanks alot!

Comment: But can you tell me what this (/\d#/g) stands for?

Comment: @YannicHansen `\d` will match a number, `#` is a symbol, and the `/g` is the global flag. So together that regex will match all the first numbers followed by a pound symbol.   eg `"test1321#a and #1 and 313#a".match(/\d#/g);` => `["1#", "3#"]`

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(document.URL.match(/\d+/g));
```

Simple. I would put it in a fiddle, but uhh, jsFiddle doesn't have any numbers in their url, so.